# How to find the difference between consecutive numbers in data set?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data set in an excel spreadsheet that goes 120, 121, 125, 127, 130, 138, 142, ....and so on. If I want to find the difference between two consecutive data points in a different column, so if I wanted the data set 121-120, 125-121, 127-125, 130-127, 138-130, 142-138..., how would I do that? I would want a new column next to it that would say 1, 4, 2, 3, 8, 4, ... Preemptive thanks to those who can help!

Thanks!

Comment: You give the answer in the question.  Have you tried what you wrote (using cell references instead of the content value)?

Answer (score 2):

*I'm assuming that you have set of consecutive numbers in column A.*

Write either of the formulas in `B2` & fill down.

```
=Abs(A3-A2)
```

**Note,** you may avoid using ABS function if don't care about `+/-` values.

Then your formula should as simple as this.

```
=(A3-A2)
```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*